# scala assign value based on Option variable

Tags: scala

New to scala and Option

I have var1 as `var1: Option[Boolean] = None`

I have var2 as val `var2: Value = Value(name = "test")`

I want to have var2 to "" if var1 is false or keep current value.

Someting like? `val var3 = var2 if var1==true else ""`

similar to python

```
if var1 == false:
   var2 = None          #(or "")
else:
   var2 = "test"         #(or current value)
```

Comment: `val var2 = var1.flatMap(b => if (b) Some("tests") else None)`

Comment: thanks Luis can I assign to var3 or standard practice is to update var2?

Comment: The standard practice is to never modify variables, that is why we use `val` instead of `var`, maybe you want to take a look to `for` comprehensions and pick any **Scala** course or tutorial

Comment: Also, there is a big difference between `Some("")` and `None` so decide which one you really want. Also a `Option[Boolean]` is kind of weird TBH. Maybe it would be best if you can describe the meta-problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are trying to use [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) as if you still in [Python](https://www.python.org/). Not sure what exactly are you trying to solve here. Based on the details you gave in the question, you can solve your problem in different ways:

### Using methods from [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html) class:

```scala
val value1         = Option(someBooleanProvided)
val valueFiltered  = value1.filter(val1 => val1) // this could also be written as `.filter(identity)`
val valueMapped    = valueFiltered.map(_ => someStringValueProvided)
val valueUnwrapped = valueFilteredAndMapped.getOrElse(emptyString)
```

Lets explain line by line what is happening:

- [Option.filter](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html#filter(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option%5BA%5D): if the value is `true`, you will get the some `Option` with no changes. If it is false, you will get a `None`
- [Option.map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):Option%5BB%5D): if the `Option` is a `Some`, you will get a new `Option` with the value returned inside `map`. If the `Option` is a `None`, you will get a `None` again.
- [Option.getOrElse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html#getOrElse%5BB%3E:A%5D(default:=%3EB):B): if the `Option` is a `Some` you will get the value contained inside the `Option` (an `String` in this case). If the value is a `None`, you will get the value passed inside the function `getOrElse`.

### Using [For Comprehensions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html):

```scala
val val2 = for {
  val1 <- Option(someBooleanProvided) if val1 
} yield someStringValueProvided
val valueUnwrapped = val2.getOrElse(emptyString)
```

As it explained in the docs, this is just a syntax sugar for `flatMap`, `map` and `withFilter`. In this case the `if` is the same as filter in the previous example, the `yield` is the same as when we used `map`. The last line is the same.

### Using [Pattern Matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html):

```scala
val value2 = Option(someBooleanProvided) match {
  case Some(true) => someStringProvided
  case _ => emptyString
}
```

This is similar to a `switch case`, but you can check types and values.

---

That being said, I suggest to not do that. The article [Baeldung - The Option Type in Scala](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/option-type) might help you to understand a bit more how to use it. The idea of the `Option` type, is to model the absence of data. The methods `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` and some others are not exclusive from `Option`. Those ones, lets you chain different operations without being worried about if the value is present or not. Once we need it, we can extract the value or use a default value in case there is no value.

---

These concepts comes from [functional programming](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/functional-programming) (it's not mandatory to use this paradigm, but you will not be taking advantage of some features that scala offers). A couple of them that are frequently used in `Scala` are:

- [Immutable values](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/fp-immutable-values.html): once a value is created, it can be changed. If you want to update a value of something that it was already created, you have to create a new instance with the new value.
  In Scala you can use [val or var](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/taste-vars-data-types.html).

| Variable type | Description |
| --- | --- |
| val | Creates an immutable variable—like final in Java. You should always create a variable with val, unless there’s a reason you need a mutable variable. |
| var | Creates a mutable variable, and should only be used when a variable’s contents will change over time. |

- [Higher order functions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html): we could say that is an ad-hoc polymorphism. Instead of having a parent class with a child classes and each one has a different implementation for each method, you can pass a function as an argument.

---

I will also suggest to check the following links

- [Tour of scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html)
- [Baeldung - Intro to Scala](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/scala-intro)
- [Recommended books](https://docs.scala-lang.org/books.html)